# Memory Segments in C — Text Segment

Tags: c, memory, text, segment

Can someone tell me what is a 'text segment' in C, and if possible show me a simple example?

Comment: segments are not programming concepts, they're how code and data are laid out in executable files and in memory when a program is running.  Take a look at the documentation for your linker for some possible hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'text' segment of a program on Unix systems is the code — the machine code, the functions that make up the program (including, in particular, `main()` if the program is written in C or C++).  It can also include read-only data.  The other segments in a classic program are the 'data' segment and the 'bss' segment.  The 'data' segment holds initialized data; the 'bss' segment holds zeroed data.  Once running, the data and bss segments are indistinguishable.

You also end up with the stack and 'the heap'.

Comment: Yes I've understood all other memory segments. So correct me if i'm wrong the main() in a c program is the text segment?

Comment: The `main()` is _in_ the text segment; so are the functions it calls.

Comment: Great that's what I wanted to know :)